# Как выполнить математическое действие, заданное в строке

Tags: c#, .net

Даны строка и число:

```
int rowNumber = 5;
var str = "%00002047{(11*rowNumber):D3}";
```

Необходимо вычислить математическое действие (умножение) между константой (`11`) и переменной (`rowNumber`), после чего результат преобразовать по формату (`D3`) и вставить в начальную строку.

Математические действия могут быть `+-/*`.

Порядок задания константы и числа может быть любым: `(11*rowNumber)` или `(rowNumber*11)`.

Последовательность действий:

```
11*5=55
формат D3 = 055
вставка результата = "%00002047055";
```

Как выделить действие (умножение, например), константу, и как вставить обратно в строку результат? Если ли типовое решение, например, через регулярное выражение?

Comment: А в чём вопрос и с чем у вас возникла проблема при решении задачи?

Comment: Как выделить действие (умножение например), константу, и  как вставить обратно в строку результат. Если это типовое решение например через регулярные выражение то приведите пример пожалуйста.

Comment: 1. Переменная всегда `rowNumber` используется? 2. В загадочный формат `D3` вы в состоянии сами перевести число? 3. Строки - штука, в общем случае, неизменяемая, так что в итоге будет собираться новая строка.

Comment: да rowNumber всегда используеться, формат не загадочный а взят из из ToString("D3"). хорошо бы добавить поддержку нескольких мат. действий например rowNumber*11+10. Все что вы написали я знаю. если не сложно напишите алгоритм парсинга.

Comment: Ну нет - одна операция решается "топорным" способом с помощью рег. выражения. А вот несколько операций/действий уже требуют полноценный парсер, так что это уже совсем другой разговор.

Comment: пусть 1 операция для примера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56344/discussion-between-aldmi-and-regent).

Comment: Нет, давайте обойдёмся без чата. Код для описанной в вопросе задачи я написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для данных конкретных условий получается так (при условии что строка корректна).

Парсинг строки:

1. Нужно сохранить символы до `{`.
2. Нужно сохранить константу, которая идёт либо до оператора, либо после него.
3. Нужно сохранить оператор (который, соответственно, идёт либо до константы, либо после неё).
4. Нужно сохранить формат, находящийся между `:` и `}`.
5. Нужно сохранить символы после `}`.

Расчет арифметического выражения:

1. Нужно определиться что идёт первым: `rowNumber` или константа.
2. Посчитать результат с учетом значения оператора и порядка операндов.

Формирование итоговой строки:

1. Преобразование арифметического результата по формату из 4го пункта парсинга.
2. Конкатенация 1го пункта парсинга с преобразованным арифм. результатом и с 5м пунктом парсинга.

Итоговый код:

```
public static string Format(string str, int rowNumber)
{
    string signPattern = @"([\+\-\/\*])";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*)\{\((\w+" + signPattern + @"(\d+)|(\d+)" +
            signPattern + @"\w+)\)\:(\w+)\}(.*)");
    Match match = regex.Match(str);
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        return str;
    }
    GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
    bool directOrder = (groups[3].Length > 0);
    int operatorIndex = directOrder ? 3 : 6;
    int numberIndex = directOrder ? 4 : 5;
    int number = int.Parse(groups[numberIndex].Value);
    string nOperator = groups[operatorIndex].Value;
    int firstNumber = directOrder ? rowNumber : number;
    int secondNumber = directOrder ? number : rowNumber;
    int resultNumber = Calculate(firstNumber, secondNumber, nOperator);
    string format = groups[7].Value;
    string packedNumber = resultNumber.ToString(format);
    return groups[1].Value + packedNumber + groups[8].Value;
}

private static int Calculate(int a, int b, string nOperator)
{
    switch (nOperator)
    {
        case "+": return a + b;
        case "-": return a - b;
        case "*": return a * b;
        case "/": return a / b;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Регулярное выражение:

1. Какие-то символы
2. Символы `{(`
3. (группа букв/цифр + операнд + группа цифр) ИЛИ (группа цифр + операнд + группа букв/цифр)
4. Символы `):`
5. Группа букв/цифр
6. Символ `}`
7. Какие-то символы

"группа букв/цифр" из пункта 3 - это `rowNumber`. "группа цифр" из пункта 3 - это константа. "группа букв/цифр" из пункта 5 - это формат.

Группы захвата:

0: Всё найденное выражение
1: Символы до `{`
2: Подстрока из оператора и операндов
3: Оператор, если `rowNumber` идёт первым операндом
4: Константа, если `rowNumber` идёт первым операндом
5: Константа, если `rowNumber` идёт вторым операндом
6: Оператор, если `rowNumber` идёт вторым операндом
7: Формат
8: Символы после `}`

Comment: Спасибо Работает! А можно поподробнее расписать само рег. выражение и что получается в коллекции групп?

Comment: @Aldmi расписал в конце ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое !!

Comment: @Aldmi на здоровье. Если что - нумерация групп в ответе сначала неправильно отобразилась. Там от `0` до `8`.